# AngularJS TemplateUrl doesn't bind to $scope

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I know this question has been asked before, but I looked at them all, and couldn't find anything. Here is basically what I have:

**Layout.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
   ...
   <div my-container></div>
   ...
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', [] );
App.directive('myContainer', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/path/to/view.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.param = 3; 
        }
    }
});
```

**view.html**

```
<div>
   {{ param }}
</div>
```

On run, `view.html` is loaded, but I still see `{{ param }}`. I really don't understand why! Please advise.

---

Here is my exact code. I am using Laravel with AngularJS. My hierarchy is as followed:

```
/app
   /app
      ... Laravel back-end, including the layout.blade.php
   /bootstrap
   /public
       /app
           /views
               miniCalendar.html
           /controllers
           /lib
           ...
           app.js
       index.php
```

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('mainApp', [] );    
App.directive('miniCalendar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/views/miniCalendar.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.title = 'March'; // This is just an example.
    }
}
```

});

**miniCalendar.html**

```
<block mini-calendar class="full-content block mini-calendar" name="mini-calendar">
   <!-- Code here -->
   <span class="large-10 columns text-bold ti" ng-hide="hide" ng-click='headerToggle()'>{{ title }}</span>
   <!-- Code here -->
</block>
```

Comment: may be after removing the forward slash from the beginning of  `path/to/view.html`.

Comment: The path isn't an issue because I DO get the DOM replaced with the elements from the view.html. The scope however, remain as {{ ... }}

Comment: Do you see any other error in browser console? If there are, then the digest cycle gets obstructed and directives are not compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path was probably wrong ,I tested your code and it worked, here's a live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/d5rgPAj1nPIxcqSrqCD1?p=preview

Comment: But i get the path to work. The elements are replaced, except the {{ }} remain as {{ }} brackets!

Comment: have you checked my example?

Comment: Yes i did. And I am now very confused why yours works and mine doesn't. Cause, again I am getting all the elements placed in the right place.

Comment: you can add your code and we'll try to check the problem

Comment: did you remove the forward slash from the beginning of the path just use "app/views/miniCalendar.html" ?

Comment: @user834045 You can using the directive `mini-calendar` again in the template `miniCalendar.html`?

Comment: I noticed if I remove mini-calendar from the <block> tag, everything works. Why is that? The reason I kept that tag was because I need to later dynamically replace that DOM again, so I wanted to use the same code again.

Comment: It will keep on replacing the DOM whenever the directive is compiled. It is not a good practice, I assume. You have to come up with some other way I guess.